# Increase the score who eats more than five times

Tags: javascript

I can Drag and drop the images into the baskets who eats once a week

what if a person eats the food item more than five times a week or he never eats the item?

For example,  If a person who eats a watermelon once a week, try to drag and release the watermelon image from Items to basket  the points increase by 30.

What if the same person who eats the watermelon five times a week,How to increase his score?

Here is a script

```
var myscore=0;
function dragStart(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed='move';
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.getAttribute('id'));
  ev.dataTransfer.setDragImage(ev.target,0,0);
  return true;
}
function dragEnter(ev) {
  event.preventDefault();
  return true;
}
function dragOver(ev) {
  return false;
}
function dragDrop1(ev) {   
  var src = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  if(!ev.target.contains(document.getElementById(src))){
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(src));
    ev.stopPropagation();
    var cal=0;
    switch(src){
      case "image1": cal = 20; break;
      case "image2": cal = 30; break;
      case "image3": cal = 40; break;
      case "image4": cal = 50; break;
      case "image5": cal = 60; break;
      default: cal=10;
    }
    myscore=myscore-cal;
    document.getElementById('Score').innerHTML=myscore;
  }
  return true;
}
function dragDrop2(ev) {   
  var src = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  if(!ev.target.contains(document.getElementById(src))){
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(src));
    ev.stopPropagation();
    var cal=0;
    switch(src){
      case "image1": cal = 20; break;
      case "image2": cal = 30; break;
      case "image3": cal = 40; break;
      case "image4": cal = 50; break;
      case "image5": cal = 60; break;
      default: cal=10;
    }
    myscore=myscore+cal;
    document.getElementById('Score').innerHTML=myscore;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesrod9000/sj0ssp68/1/)

Comment: That is a very nice way to put the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here's the deal. I added a function to duplicate the food div, thus allowing you to drag and drop it as many times as you want.

```
function duplicate(x) {
    var clone = x.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = "" 
    clone.onclick = duplicate;
    x.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, x.nextSibling);
}
```

Here 's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sj0ssp68/4/).

This way you can put as many watermelons as you want. The problem is that you can multiply the items inside by clicking on them. I don't have enough time to fix the bugs but it is something you can think over on your own for now. When I have time I'll clean the script.

PS: I changed the ids to classes, for multiplication purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the improved version ,I could not get over this bug--But there is a small bug- -like If I drag and Drop the images from the items list into the items list, the images disappear,and If i drag and drop the images from the basket list to the basket list the images, more image appears.Also  there is a fluctuation of the scores by 10 points for the drag and drop after the initial value..like if I drag and drop the images from the item list to the item list nothing changes should take place and If I drag and drop the image from basket to basket no change should take place

Comment: @James is it better [now](http://jsfiddle.net/sj0ssp68/6/)? You just had to save the origin of the field and check if it's still in the same box upon dropping ;)